# Running chkrootkit shows me suspicious files and directories

Tags: kubuntu

I run a test to see if I have been hacked. And I get this response:

```
Searching for suspicious files and dirs, it may take a while... The following suspicious files and directories were found:  
/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo /usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/tests/baseline_images/.keep /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit /usr/lib/debug/.build-id /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/vdso/.build-id /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-64-generic/vdso/.build-id /usr/lib/nvidia-visual-profiler/.eclipseproduct
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/vdso/.build-id /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-64-generic/vdso/.build-id
```

Is this something wrong with all these information? Running 'who' and 'last' commands didn't show something not normal however.

Comment: "I run a test to see if I have been hacked."  Please explainwhat servers you have running that allow access to your system (apache? teamviewer? openssh? gameserver?). If you do not have any of those you will not get hacked by a random internet user. Oh and chrootkit does not tell you if you got hacked; it scans for rootkits. A hacker with skills does not leave a rootkit on your system but enters and extracts data on the fly.  Getting proof of a hacker is done by examining  the log of your router: search for incoming traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chkrootkit` has pointed out files that "looked' suspicious, but didn't match any of the patterns that `chkrootkit` knows about.

It's up to you to explore the files with commands like (`ls -la`, `dpkg -S`, `file -k`, `stat`, `od -bc`, `less`, ... ) and decide whether they represent a threat to your system.

Figuring out why `chkrootkit` complained is helpful.

Is the file "hidden" by beginning with a "`.`"?

Is the file executable? Setuid?

What's the file size? If 0, it could be a flag file, if nonzero, what's it contain?

Read (not execute) text files, inspect others.